# In plotly dash, how do I source a local image file to dash.html.Img?

Tags: python, html, image, plotly

This is how to source a local image file to the `<img>` element in html:

```
<html>
    <h1>This is an image</h1>
    <img src="file:///C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/Plotly_Dash_logo.png" alt="image"></img>
</html>
```

This displays the image as expected. But when I try to make the same page using the plotly dash wrapper elements, it does not work:

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('This is an image'),
    html.Img(src=r'file:///C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/Plotly_Dash_logo.png', alt='image'),
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=False, use_reloader=False)
```

The local image file does not display. But if I replace the source with a file from the internet, like `'https://rapids.ai/assets/images/Plotly_Dash_logo.png'`, it works just fine.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some more searching, I found that I could place my image file in a folder named "assets/", then reference it relative to the app folder.

```
html.Img(src=r'assets/Plotly_Dash_logo.png', alt='image')
```

I could also use a special method of the app instance `dash.Dash.get_asset_url()`.

```
html.Img(src=app.get_asset_url('my-image.png'))
```

Source: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-enterprise/static-assets

Answer (score 4):

I used another way:

- open the image file and read the contents
- encode the data by base64 and decode it
- add "data:image/jpg;base64, " in front of the string (replace jpg with png for png format images)
- set string as src

```py
with open(imgfile, "rb") as image_file:
    img_data = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    img_data = img_data.decode()
    img_data = "{}{}".format("data:image/jpg;base64, ", img_data)
    # ...
    html.Img(id="tag_id", src=img_data, alt="my image", width="200", height="400", 
    className="img_class")
```

Comment: ... but why do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the solution provided in this old GitHub issue :
https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/71

It seems it's not built for local urls :?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this interactively (for example if you want to render the image every minute or something)

Include this div, img in your layout:

```
html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Img(
            id='figure-image-test',
            # define this in styles.css
            className='figure',
        ),
    ],
    # define this in styles.css
    className='figure-row',
),
```

Update `src` with:

```
@app.callback(
    dash.Output(component_id='figure-image-test', component_property='src'),
    dash.Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),
)
def update_charts(n_intervals):
    print(f'refreshing {datetime.now()}, {n_intervals}')

    # this will write the image file to `./assets/my_figure.png`
    tmp_filename = f'{os.getcwd()}/assets/my_figure.png'

    # create an image file using matplotlib
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4.5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.scatter(x, y)
    fig.savefig(tmp_filename)

    return (
        # src should be set to: src='assets/my_figure.png'
        'assets/my_figure.png'
    )
```

`interval-component` should be a

```
dcc.Interval(
    id='interval-component',
    interval=10 * 1000, # 10 seconds
    n_intervals=0,
)
```

which you also include in the layout.